# Is bandwagon voting thru chat voting fraud?

Tags: discussion, voting, voting-fraud

- Voting with socks is abuse, since the socks don't evaluate the quality of the post, the votes are low quality.
- Serial voting is abuse, since you don't fully evaluate the quality of every post, the votes are low quality.

Should bandwagon voting through chat (i.e. asking for everyone to up/down-vote a post) be considered abuse? You're less likely to fully evaluate the quality of the post, but the people themselves in the chatroom will tend to share the same views anyway . And they might have certain biases.

*For example*, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24988713/2371861) which got up to +6/-1, when I woke up it had 8 more downvotes. When I replied to comments on it, it got 3 more downvotes in a short period of time. How?

- [This is where my answer was discovered and posted to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17955303#17955303).
- [This is when the second round of downvotes
  came](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17957779#17957779).
- [This is when this meta post was magically downvoted to -8, before
  climbing slowly up
  again.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17958319#17958319)

Comment: If you are referring to a specific incident, please refer to it explicitly. You can create a shareable 'conversation' link by going to the room menu and choosing 'create new bookmark'.

Comment: certainly not the first time the issue has been raised, but the answer is going to be that it's fine

Comment: @TomMedley he is talking about his answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988686/javascript-replace-newline-escape-sequence-with-newline/24988713#24988713 which I personally downvoted because it _is a bad answer_. I also ran into it reading minitech's posts which when I got there was downvoted and verbally abused (imo) by bjb. I left a professional comment on the post explaining why I believe it is wrong and asked the people in the JS room what their opinion was.

Comment: Your answer was not "magically downvoted". In the JS room we have very experienced coders that don't take any affirmation as true just because it's in bold and ends with an exclamation mark. The JS chat room **is** a place where you can find a good critical read of an answer.

Comment: As for the specific case - you can note I who brought it to the chat I did not ask anyone to downvote or upvote it or even vote on it at all... However - my oldest questions got two magical downvotes. If you just fix your answer I'll gladly revert the downvote, like I said. That's what downvotes are used for on answers mostly after all...

Comment: Just to add another perspective, this is effectively how all review queues work ie asking others to review and cast a decision, the only major difference being the amount of rep required to be a part of any review queue is > 20 (the amount to chat).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Should bandwagon voting through chat (i.e. asking for everyone to up/down-vote a post) be considered abuse?

People coordinates all kind of efforts through chat. If you make any kind of behavior "fraudulent" you should also include:

- flagging spam
- voting to close
- voting to reopen
- voting to delete
- voting to undelete
- etc.

That people are made aware of a specific post that merits attention through chat is not in and on itself fraudulent. You can ask in a chat room for voting in an specific way for a post, that doesn't mean that everyone will do as you ask.

Comment: Hm... but if it's specifically instructed to vote up/down (instead of just looky here!), isn't that different? Up/down votes are the only votes that get automatically reversed, so they seem special.

Comment: @bjb568 you are entitled to vote as you feel like. In fact, there are auto flags for close and delete votes also, so up/down voting is not really that special.

Answer (score 20):

No. Just because we're in a chat doesn't mean we don't think freely. Even if somebody says "hey go vote this down", nobody (yes I know you mean the JS Room) says "Ok screw this guy -1 for a good answer"

No. They read it. They agree with the other person, and they vote. Those who blindly vote based on others, while not wrong (they can vote however they like), is a bad idea. Keyword, not wrong.

All popular chat rooms post good and bad (mostly bad for closing) questions and answers.

Comment: Not nobody, but I agree for *most people*.

Answer (score 15):

Bringing questions and answers into discussion in chat rooms happens. In fact it is quite common. We discuss questions and answers on the site all the time.

Discussing questions in chat rooms naturally prompts chat room users to vote on them since well... people believe voting is important for SO. Since voting is confidential - I don't recall an instance where a user is asked to or forced to vote.

This is no different from a question being discussed on Hacker News, Reddit, Twitter etc except in this case the users are from the site so they actually understand the system and not from a distant community. In fact - this has been very helpful in some cases, for example closing bad questions in the php room.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to tell you this, but even as a non-JS programmer-  your answer is bad.  The problem with regexes are complex regexes which are difficult to read.  This is a simple one that's easy to understand-  a good use of regex.  A replaceAll function would be a better solution, but you wrote a poor one-  it requires the creation of possibly dozens of temporary objects (an array of strings) and then recreates them.  That's a large amount of work and effort for something so simple.  Now if you want to write a real in-place replaceAll function I'd probably upvote it.

Basically I see no problem here, much less a record of bad behavior that would mean we need to take some sort of action.

Comment: "The problem with regexes are complex regexes which are difficult to read." So if OP decided to modify the regex and got confused, you'd be surprised? OP already got confused, causing the question. "you wrote a poor one" I wasn't aiming for efficiency.

Comment: You should have aimed for efficiency.  The point of this site is to give good answers.  Not mediocre ones.  And yours was mediocre at best.  Mediocre is acceptable only when there is no good one-  and fixing a trivial regex is a good one.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Comment: Yeah, there's a reason that argument by authority is a logical fallacy.  Just because Jeff Atwood thinks something doesn't make him right.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I linked to his article because it presented good reasoning.

Comment: Great.  And I've read it.  Overall I'm not impressed by it.  Attitudes like that are holding back the field of programming, its why every new version of software I get runs slower than it did on my old computer.  And with Moore's law dieing its going to punch us in the balls very soon.  But even ignoring that you're mis-applying what he meant.  He meant not to throw out an easy solution with a more complicated but slightly more efficient solution.  You're throwing out the easy solution (a trivial regex) for a more complicated and less efficient solution.  That's a fail.