# Prolog Absurdistan on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

The [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog) tag is getting more and more unusable. The quality of the content is degrading.

Many times I step into posts characterizable by:

- Pumping each others' score by coalition formation: 
  The users post questions and answers which give opportunity to get votes or bounties while no real content is produced. The users belong to a particular group.

  There are two relatively high bounties awarded. One of the awarded answers obviously being an Aprils fool answer.
- Polluting Stack Overflow with sketch book rubbish: 
  The posted answers are not real answers, but just sketches. In the particular example linked below a single user has produced five answers.

  That these answers are sketches is not only my idea. It is also expressed by the poster himself by exclamations such as "Third try!", "Next!" and then "What the heck!".

Typical example for both diseases as I see it: [How to define (and name) the corresponding safe term comparison predicates in ISO Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720685/safe-term-order)

Is this desired behavior? I don't think Stack Overflow is designed as a playground. What can be done against such kinds of questions and answer flooding? Is this already discussed somewhere on meta?

P.S. What's also happening a lot under this tag is answering questions in comments and not by proper answers.

Comment: What's wrong with your example question? I see a clearly defined technical question with detailed background, resulting in several detailed answers. There's no indication whatsoever of voting fraud or other shenanigans there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear

Comment: Ok, was looking for these terms "voting fraud" and "shenanigans". What can be done against misusing SO as a sketch book?

Comment: I think what the OP means is that try same person answered that question 5 times @brad; not in itself indicative of any voting fraud at all, and perfectly fine if the answers are distinct. I'm unqualified to say whether they are.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question because I think it's clear what is asked.

Answer (score 14):

> Pumping each others score by coalition formation.

That might be called [voting fraud](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266994/is-bandwagon-voting-thru-chat-voting-fraud) but us mortals can't prove that. You are better off using a custom flag so moderators can verify if patterns exist. Keep in mind that on small tags, you're are more likely to run into the [same clever minds](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/topusers).

> Polluting Stack Overflow with sketch book rubbish.

I can't judge that, but if the rubbish from the sketchbook is well asked, on-topic, and not too broad I don't see much of a problem. Neither is having multiple answers from the same user a problem. If the Q/A attracts visitors that might need such sketchbook post to get started in prolog, all is good. If there is more than just one example I might revisit my point of view.

> Answering questions in comments and not by proper answers.

You can always post an answer yourself based on the comments if a gentle nudge of the commenter didn't work. Make it Community Wiki to prevent being insulted for inflating your rep at the expense of others.

> What can be done against it?

Use your voting abilities like close voting and down voting to signal potential issues with questions or answers. You could also explain what is troublesome about a post in a comment. That is about it.

Comment: I fully agree,  @j4nbur53 already has full powers of moderation to keep their  favorite tag clean as possible. May be noteworthy that on a small niche like [tag:prolog] there will be only a handful of established expert users active, which might make these looking like something of a _"voting ring"_.

Comment: Cleaning up is a lot of work. SO might have some automated indicators for such abuse. Like limiting the number of answers the same author can give. Etc.. This is what first came to my mind, there should be some automated barriers.

Comment: Yes, don't get me started on cleaning up. But based on the evidence so far I don't see much need for that. Prolog isn't PHP ...

Comment: Its not 100% clear that pseudonyms such as mat, false and repeat etc. are distinct persons. I have already cracked one pseudonyms, but the others are still obscure to me and maybe shared identities. Anyway, where there is light, there is also shadow. Cant help this behaviour.

Comment: @j4nbur53 _"Cant help this behaviour."_ Considering there's no evidence of any behavior, at least in your example, that is against the rules, you're right. There's nothing wrong with one person posting multiple answers so long as they are different answers. (I am not able to say for sure here.) In fact, it's _encouraged_ to put different solutions in different answers, so they can be voted on properly. After all, if you have two solutions in one answer, and one is bad while the other is great... How would someone vote on that?

Comment: Its not my judgement that the answers are sketch book answers. The answer poster himself titles the answers as such. You find headings like "Third try!", "Next!" and then "What the heck!". Its not my idea that the answers are sketch book entries.

Comment: @j4nbur53 is it still a sketchbook answer if you remove the heading? If the answers were warranted to be posted separately because they were using quite different approach, but still working and useful, then I see no harm. Though, I can't judge its technicality (not a Prolog guy).

Comment: An other user is introducing his answer with "Here is a sketch of what I believe might be a working approach". SO is used as a playground. I don't mind if this is would be in the scope of SO, but I doubt that it is if it is practiced so extensively.

Comment: @j4nbur53 My first reaction when I saw user "repeat" post repeated answers was the same: why not edit the current answer with a definitive one? SO keeps the different versions anyway, and I understand why you feel that there is too much clutter. On the other hand, there are not many people answering Prolog questions and as a consequence the number of actual answers is still low compared to the ones for popular tags. I also don't think that there is a coalition or conspiracy.

Comment: @Kendra. "*In fact, it's* **encouraged** *to put different solutions in different answers, so they can be voted on properly.*" Exactly! I couldn't agree more...

Comment: @coredump. I *do* get your point! OTOH no answer may turn out to be *the* single one "definitive" answer. I think this is in fact to be expected, as the implementation space—term traversal (implicit/explicit), ISO-standard compliance (yes/no), complexity (P/NP), runtime efficiency (fast/slow), behavior with cyclic terms (tame/wild)—indeed **is** of considerable size.

Comment: @repeat I guess the ideal answer would bring a synthetic view of the problem and discuss the merits of different approaches, possibly building up onto other ones. Personally I am reluctant to post multiple answers (and maybe I should try) but I am not there to dictate what others should do ;-)

Comment: @coredump. I agree. OTOH there may not be a single right way out... Uh-oh, we're getting too "meta":)

Comment: Let me state for the record:
The question was asked Nov 3 **2014**. 
Answer #1 (Nov 3, mat) was soon retracted.
Answer #2 (Nov 14, coredump) had issues.
Answer #3 (Jan 11 **2015**, Tudor Berariu): progress, but still problems.
Answer #4 (May 5, me): still incorrect.
Answer #5 (May 7, false): suggested a promising direction.
Answer #6 (May 7, me): still incorrect.
Answer #7 (May 9, me): the 1st correct one, but inefficient and not ISO-compliant.
Answer #8 (Dec 1, me): based on explicit term traversal and coroutining.
Answer #9 (Dec 2, me): a generalization of safe `(@<)/2` to safe `compare/3`.

Answer (score -14):

The group that has a certain research agenda and that is using SO as a sketch book and playground to develop new code should move to Git, Gist or something similar. Or maybe to the code review stack exchange.

> Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
>   Git: https://github.com/
>   Gist: https://gist.github.com/

On such a medium the group can also place code snippets or even whole programs, and its also possible to comment the code. Further it is easy to copy lengthy excerpts of standards etc.. And place appropriate [licensing terms](https://www.gitbook.com/book/tra38/essential-copying-and-pasting-from-stack-overflow/details).

As an additional benefit is that such a medium has good syntax highlighting and also diff computation, since it keeps a history of the changes. And more importantly this medium is much better suited to the size and coherence of material.

The drawback is that most of these media have no scoring system. And that it doesn't automatically attract so much attention, execept if the group members would write good blogs, specs, etc...

The group could still publish its results on SO from time to time, if related to some serious questions and thus attract attention.

Comment: P.S.: I would be myself a user of such a code, spec, etc.. trove! Especially when it covers constraint solvers and novel ways and application areas.

Comment: Code Review is probably not the place for these kinds of sketchbook/playground kinds of questions. It has [its own rules](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what works there.

Comment: To get a feeling what it means for solutions to the same problem being really different in character and thus of interest for the end-user I recommend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK the first chapter, which shows 6 different proofs for the infinity of primes.