# Is [prolog-lists] needed when there is [prolog] and [list]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The newly introduced tag [prolog-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-lists) appears to be redundant and better be replaced by [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) which in [conjunction with Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog+list) shows 1.7k posts.

Note that there are already cases like [prolog-cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-cut) and [cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cut). But the situation looks different. [cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cut) refers to a Unix tool, whereas [prolog-cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-cut) refers to the control construct `!/0` of Prolog. So [prolog-cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-cut) is not a strict subset of [cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cut). In fact it is completely disjoint. It's also hard to imagine a question that would carry both tags. Same for [prolog-dif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-dif), [prolog-assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-assert), [prolog-setof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-setof), [prolog-findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-findall).

And since there is [no question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-lists+-prolog) that isn't also [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog), the tag can be merged with [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list).

Comment: Do you want people that have gold badges on python lists to be able to close questions on prolog? If the answer is no, then no, you don't want to have list on prolog questions.

Comment: @Braiam: Someone with a gold badge should know how to use [Mjölnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332618/mj%c3%b6lnir-use-guide) well. So this does not seems to be a concern. Otherwise, all language independent tags should be renamed similarly.

Comment: @Braiam What does it mean *"gold badges on python lists"*? If you mean people that got the gold badge of `list` from answering Python questions, then there is a much wider problem: there are 13,852 C# questions tagged `list` that those *pythonistas* can close... Anyway, same can be said about [[tag:string]], for example (which is used with basically all language tags), and many others

Comment: A bit of further check shows that a specific user added this tag about two weeks ago. As there are only 10 questions, officially there is no need for a burnination and you can just remove the tag. I doubt it will get created again but we can't know. For the time being, since its creation, no one actually used it explicitly in a new question (all 10 occurrences are edited-in by the same user)

Comment: @Tomerikoo: I have [good reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319598/772868) not to.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I was using the example that [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408341/792066) provided, but yes. That's why I am very against of creating combo tags, the system simply isn't designed that way.

Comment: @false you may want to read [my proposal about language generic tags.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300700/792066) TL;dr most questions shouldn't use them.

Comment: What would be the consequences for [tag:integer], [tag:string], [tag:boolean], [tag:numbers], [tag:arrays], [tag:queue], [tag:stack], [tag:dictionary], [tag:object], [tag:null], [tag:types], [tag:function], [tag:class], [tag:set], [tag:reference], [tag:pointers], [tag:linked-list], [tag:queue], [tag:heap], [tag:tree], ...etc.

Comment: For the argument about a Python user using their [list] gold badge on Perl questions, _that_ is fine. We trust users who own gold badges enough to vote to close posts as duplicate. If they're abusing it, voting to close Perl posts as dupe of Python ones, jumping the gun with wrong targets and so on, _then_ it would be an issue.

Comment: @BhargavRao I just don't trust them. Regex is already a mess. I prefer reducing the opportunities of having to trust them, so make the system work as it's supposed to.

Comment: @trincot probably something about (pulls number out a hat) 97.6% of the question should have those tags removed. It is not constructive to have every concept that a question uses as a question, like django models that uses classes, you don't need to tag class for every question that involves models.

Answer (score 9):

There was [a similar discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376784/what-is-python-list-good-for) about [python-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-list).

The final result from that seems to be that `python-list` became a synonym of [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list). I don't see any reason for not doing the same here.

I have already [proposed the synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/list/synonyms).

---

To my knowledge, a synonym only affects ***new usages*** of the tag. So, the existing questions will remain the same. Question remains: if/when the synonym will be accepted, should the existing questions be retagged or a moderator needs to merge them?

---

Following the synonym approval, here are the 9 questions with the original tag:

- [Convert Binary to decimal predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67839517/6045800)
- [Repeat and Double elements in lists in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62119598/6045800)
- [Append lists in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22236475/6045800)
- [I am wondering about prolog lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19278163/6045800)
- [Prolog Lists - Duplicate head](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53504691/6045800)
- [Comparing prolog lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36284326/6045800)
- [SICStus Prolog Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12336119/6045800)
- [Understanding Prolog Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54054858/6045800)
- [Find combinations of elements of size bigger than the number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60806346/6045800)

Comment: The synonym is now done. And don't worry about it, everything is fine.

Comment: A manual merge by a moderator is required. Generally, we hold off for a while before doing this, as the synonym can be easily canceled, but it's much harder to restore things once they've been merged.